# iOS - Is there a good way to clean up HTML code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsxmlparser, htmltidy

In my app I am pulling in some HTML content from the web.  Sometimes that markup isn't the most valid looking code and I would like to clean it up (fixing markup errors, etc.), similar to how HTMLTidy works.

**Someone mentioned libTidy, but I find nothing about how to use it, so let me ask, what is the best way to clean up HTML to be more valid in iOS?**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24794675. It describes how to create a modulemap file so you can include libTidy.

br
denis