# What is Swift Compiler - Search Paths Import Paths in Xcode 6 Building Settings?

Tags: module, swift, xcode6

In Xcode 6 (Beta), there is Swift Compiler - Search Paths, Import Paths. What does it do?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just to share what I have discovered during days of connecting dots. **Short answer**, Import Search Path `SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS` specifies where Swift finds and imports modules.

#### Modules and Semantic Import

What are modules? Modules improve access to the API of software libraries by replacing the textual preprocessor inclusion model with a more robust, more efficient semantic model. From the user’s perspective, the code looks only slightly different, because one uses an import declaration rather than a #include preprocessor directive like this:

```
import std.io
```

It was first announced in Nov 2012 by Apple at LLVM DevMeeting. You can still find the Doug Gregor’s talk here ([Video](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2012-11/videos/Gregor-Modules.mp4) and [PDF](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2012-11/Gregor-Modules.pdf)). At WWDC 2013, Semantic Import was introduced on along with iOS 7, the `@import` was just for it. So it was determinant that module to be part of new language Swift. Documentation of modules can be found [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#introduction).

#### Example - How to import

To have a taste, below are steps to create an example app project with HTML Tidy library module.

- Create a Swift project (OS X or iOS) in Xcode 6
- Create a `module.map` file, and place it in a directory. E.g. `/Users/vladof/module/`

  ```
   module tidy [system] {
       header "/usr/include/tidy/tidy.h"
       header "/usr/include/tidy/buffio.h"
       link "tidy"
       export *
   }
  ```
- Go Build Settings, set `Swift Compiler - Search Paths` > `Import Paths` to the directory that you put the `module.map` file in. `/Users/vladof/module` in my case. Then you can use `import tidy` and leverage useful APIs of HTML Tidy library, even in Swift REPL.
- Import

  ```
   import tidy
  ```
- Example code

  ```
   var input: CString = "<node>upper case node</node>"
   var tdoc: TidyDoc = tidyCreate() // Initialize "document"
   var rc: Int32 = -1
   var ok = tidyOptSetBool(tdoc, TidyUpperCaseTags, yes) // Convert tags to upper cases
   ok = tidyOptSetBool(tdoc, TidyXmlTags, yes) // Convert to XML

   if ok.value == 1 {
       rc = tidyParseString(tdoc, input) // Parse the input
       if rc >= 0 {
           rc = tidyCleanAndRepair(tdoc) // Tidy it up
       }
       if rc >= 0 {
           rc = tidySaveStdout(tdoc) // Pretty print to console
       }
   }
  ```
- Print

  ```
   <NODE>upper case node</NODE>
  ```

#### Conclude

Also I have experimented with `curl` module. In fact some APIs are not imported as I test, e.g. `curl_easy_setopt()`, let’s hope they catch up in near future. But I am positive this opens a door for Swift developers.

Comment: **NOTE** CString and Bool.value are stripped out in Beta 4.

Comment: This is driving me nuts. I got it working (in my case MySQL from homebrew). But once I moved my project it shows me "No such module 'mysqlclient_r'" although I changed the path for module. I guess I will setup the project new and copy all files. I also have cleaned the DerivedData. Is there any place else I should look into?

Comment: @ThomasKilian, would this help? https://devforums.apple.com/message/1070170#1070170

Comment: Looks promising. Meanwhile I used above which worked too (but obviously more tedious). I'll keep this in mind for the next time.

Comment: Coincidently I had the error in a playground where Cocoa was not found (lol). The linked procedure solved the issue.

Comment: Found the swift compiler import paths useful when using cocoapods. Just enter Pods and make it recursive.