# Swift - Import Source File by Path?

Tags: import, terminal, swift

I've been playing around with using Swift as a scripting language, as described [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2014/06/using-swift-general-purpose-scripting-language/). When executing script files from the terminal in this way, is there a way to include other Swift files by path (i.e. `import /path/to/some/file.swift`)? I'm aware of the `import` statement, but that doesn't seem to accept a file path. In Ruby I would use a `require` statement, but I don't know if there is a Swift equivalent to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import` only works with [modules](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/accesscontrol/#Modules-and-Source-Files). If you need to import a module which is located somewhere besides the normal [import search path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24794675/23649), you can add another directory to the search paths by passing the `-I` flag to the compiler:

> `-I <value>`              Add directory to the import search path

If you're looking at just a .swift file, you'll need to compile that into a module before you can import it from a separate module or the REPL.

Comment: hey, could you elaborate this a bit? I can't get `-I` to work in commandline (terminal) to import a file

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do. If you want to import another module, -I helps the compiler find the module. If you want to add another file to your module, just add that source file to your regular compiler invocation.

Comment: I do alot of scripting in commandline - swift. I wanted to get functions from a `file.swift` into terminal so that i could run those functions. I guess I'm asking, in terminal: how would i "add that source file to your regular compiler invocation". Or do i have to do this elsewhere? 
(I'm very new to this).